# Can't find variable: navigate

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to navigate between two screen with the help of `react-navigation`. I am able to access `navigate` inside the `render` method as its scope is also inside that method.

Where should I declare so I can access it any method of this `component`. I am trying to access `navigate` inside the `onPressButton` method but it giving an error.

> Can't find variable: navigate

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, Text, Image, Button, Alert, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import styles from "./Styles";
import * as strings from "./Strings";
import RoundButton from "./RoundButton";
var DialogAndroid = require("react-native-dialogs");
import { StackNavigator } from "react-navigation";

export default class CreateMessageScreen extends Component {
  render() {  
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Image source={require("./img/create_message.png")} />
        <Text style={styles.textStyle}>{strings.create_message}</Text>

        <RoundButton
          textStyle={styles.roundTextStyle}
          buttonStyle={styles.roundButtonStyle}
          onPress={this.onPressButton}
        >
          CREATE MESSAGE
        </RoundButton>

      </View>
    );
  }

  onPressButton() {
    var options = {
      title: strings.app_name,
      content: strings.create_message,
      positiveText: strings.OK,
      onPositive: () => navigate("DashboardScreen")
    };
    var dialog = new DialogAndroid();
    dialog.set(options);
    dialog.show();
  }
}
```

Comment: Try this  const { navigation } = this.props;

Comment: @Ved I have this in `render` method `const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;`

Comment: Yes. I know.  Can you test what I asked. I will update answer in detail than.

Comment: change const { navigation } = this.props, and , onPositive: () => navigation("DashboardScreen")

Comment: @Ved Should I define `const { navigation } = this.props; ` in onPressButton() ?

Comment: I am updating answer. Check that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to move `const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;` into the `onPressButton` function instead of the `render` function (don't forget to `bind` the function so that `this` has the correct value):

```
export default class CreateMessageScreen extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    // need to bind `this` to access props in handler
    this.onPressButton = this.onPressButton.bind(this);
  }

  render() {  
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Image source={require("./img/create_message.png")} />
        <Text style={styles.textStyle}>{strings.create_message}</Text>

        <RoundButton
          textStyle={styles.roundTextStyle}
          buttonStyle={styles.roundButtonStyle}
          onPress={this.onPressButton}
        >
          CREATE MESSAGE
        </RoundButton>

      </View>
    );
  }

  onPressButton() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;

    var options = {
      title: strings.app_name,
      content: strings.create_message,
      positiveText: strings.OK,
      onPositive: () => navigate("DashboardScreen")
    };
    var dialog = new DialogAndroid();
    dialog.set(options);
    dialog.show();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Object destructuring work like this,

**Destructuring objects:**

```
const obj = { first: 'Jane', last: 'Doe' };
const {first: f, last: l} = obj;
    // f = 'Jane'; l = 'Doe'

// {prop} is short for {prop: prop}
const {first, last} = obj;
    // first = 'Jane'; last = 'Doe'
```

In Your Case:

```
1. const { navigation:navigate } = this.props;
```

or:

```
2. const {navigation} = this.props;





export default class CreateMessageScreen extends Component {
  render() {  
 const { navigation:navigate } = this.props;

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Image source={require("./img/create_message.png")} />
        <Text style={styles.textStyle}>{strings.create_message}</Text>

        <RoundButton
          textStyle={styles.roundTextStyle}
          buttonStyle={styles.roundButtonStyle}
          onPress={this.onPressButton}
        >
          CREATE MESSAGE
        </RoundButton>

      </View>
    );
  }



    onPressButton() {
  const { navigation:navigate } = this.props;
        var options = {
          title: strings.app_name,
          content: strings.create_message,
          positiveText: strings.OK,
          onPositive: () => navigate("DashboardScreen")
        };
        var dialog = new DialogAndroid();
        dialog.set(options);
        dialog.show();
      }
    }
```

Comment: Same error  I tried this but getting an error "undefined is not an object(evaluating this.props.navigation)

Comment: @Williams  change to onPress={this.onPressButton.bind(this)} and test.

Answer (score 2):

That happens because you are not destructuring it from the props as you have done in your render() function

```
onPressButton = () => {
    var {navigate} = this.props.navigation;
    var options = {
      title: strings.app_name,
      content: strings.create_message,
      positiveText: strings.OK,
      onPositive: () => navigate("DashboardScreen")
    };
    var dialog = new DialogAndroid();
    dialog.set(options);
    dialog.show();
  }
```

Comment: I tried this but getting an error "undefined is not an object(evaluating `this.props.navigation`)

Comment: Also you need to bind you onPressButton function to access the props

Comment: How to call this onPressButton now

Comment: As I added in the answer, binding can be acieved by using arrow function or in the constructor. I used the arrow function approach like `onPressButton = () => {`

Comment: Yes I see. How I can call this from `RoundButton`        `<RoundButton
          textStyle={styles.roundTextStyle}
          buttonStyle={styles.roundButtonStyle}
          onPress={() => onPressButton}
        >`

Comment: Teh way you have used it in our question will work, However you can also call it like `<RoundButton textStyle={styles.roundTextStyle} buttonStyle={styles.roundButtonStyle} onPress={() => this.onPressButton()} >` which is also another method of binding

Comment: Check this answer `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41113798/react-event-handler-bindthis-fat-arrow-or-no-fat-arrow/41113862#41113862`

Answer (score 1):

For those looking for the hooks version in react-navigation v6

```
import {useNavigation} from '@react-navigation/native
```

then inside the components call the hook

```
const someFunction = () => {
const navigate = useNavigation() 


}
```